# Radio buttons to change iFrame not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm not quite sure I've done it right, I may be using the wrong function, but :

```
<script>
    function go(loc){
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = loc;
    }
</script>
```

I want to change the iframe in the login details container to whatever page is selected via radio button ( also how do I make the first radio button auto selected?)

```
<div class="logins_details_container"><!--The top container-->
    <iframe id="iframe" src="home_schedule_iframe.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="iframe_container">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onselect = "go('maths_iframe.php')"/>Maths<br>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onselect = "go('ict_iframe.php')"/>ICT
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can I get uor Iframe code

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: You can do `onclick` rather than `onselect`

Comment: @LogicBurner I'm not sure what you mean by get but if I can help you with anything please say

Comment: @shadow No, just the iframe is not changing ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `onClick` function inspite of `onSelect`.

So the code will be like this

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function go(loc){
      console.log(loc);
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = loc; 
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="logins_details_container"><!--The top container-->
    <iframe id="iframe" src="home_schedule_iframe.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="iframe_container">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onClick= "go('maths_iframe.php')"/>Maths<br>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onClick = "go('ict_iframe.php')"/>ICT
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx2Qc/) of the running code (It won't be able to load `maths_iframe.php` and `ict_iframe.php` obviously as they are not present on the server).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    function go(loc){
        alert(loc);
        document.getElementById('myframe').src = loc;
    }
</script>

<div class="logins_details_container"><!--The top container-->
    <iframe id="myframe" src="home_schedule_iframe.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="iframe_container">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onclick = "go('maths_iframe.php')"/>Maths<br>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onclick = "go('ict_iframe.php')"/>ICT
    </form>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8wgw/1/)